# Numpy - Multi-dimensional multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I would like to multiple 3 arrays: data1 (2808702x200), S (200x200), data2(2808702x200x1).
I ran the following code

```
In [53]: data1.shape
Out[53]: (2808702, 1, 200)
In [55]: data2.shape
Out[55]: (2808702, 200, 1)
In [56]: S.shape
Out[56]: (200, 200)
In [57]: results = np.matmul(np.matmul(data1, S), data2).reshape(dd_kpy.shape[0])
```

and got the following error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/src/datasets/StrParticipantDyad.py in <module>
----> 1 results = np.matmul(np.matmul(data1, S), data2).reshape(dd_kpy.shape[0])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __array_ufunc__(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs)
   2030         self, ufunc: np.ufunc, method: str, *inputs: Any, **kwargs: Any
   2031     ):
-> 2032         return arraylike.array_ufunc(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs)
   2033
   2034     # ideally we would define this to avoid the getattr checks, but

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py in array_ufunc(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs)
    251
    252     # for binary ops, use our custom dunder methods
--> 253     result = maybe_dispatch_ufunc_to_dunder_op(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs)
    254     if result is not NotImplemented:
    255         return result

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/ops_dispatch.pyx in pandas._libs.ops_dispatch.maybe_dispatch_ufunc_to_dunder_op()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __rmatmul__(self, other)
   1497         """
   1498         try:
-> 1499             return self.T.dot(np.transpose(other)).T
   1500         except ValueError as err:
   1501             if "shape mismatch" not in str(err):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in dot(self, other)
   1466             return self._constructor_sliced(np.dot(lvals, rvals), index=left.index)
   1467         elif isinstance(rvals, (np.ndarray, Index)):
-> 1468             result = np.dot(lvals, rvals)
   1469             if result.ndim == 2:
   1470                 return self._constructor(result, index=left.index)

<__array_function__ internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: shapes (200,200) and (200,1,2808702) not aligned: 200 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 1)
```

Could anyone help explain why and how I can fix it?

Comment: How much time did you spend reading the `matmul` docs?  Did you pay attention to how array dimensions have to match?  Are you sure those are the right shapes?  Where's the (200,1,100) array?  With 3d arrays in `matmul`, the first dimension is the "batch", while the `dot` pairing is "last of A with 2nd to the last of B".

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you for responding with very nice questions. My understanding is that data1 and S do not need to have the same number of dimensions. It is said on https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html that: when S has 1 fewer dimension than data1 "it is promoted to a matrix by appending a 1 to its dimensions. After matrix multiplication the appended 1 is removed."

Comment: I am not sure why (200,1,100) appears in the error tho. Let me post what I actually got from running my code.

Comment: @hpaulj I think I have 2808702 batches of arrays 1x200  --> what I am trying to do is having 2808702 batches of having d[1x200] . s[200x200] . d[200x1] = r[1x1]

Comment: Hi, how is the product you want to do? I mean what's the expected output shape? wich dimension will match wich other in every array?

Comment: @UlisesBussi I want an output with a shape of (2808702, ). Since my dataset has 2,808,702 rows, I do not want to go row by row and conduct d1[1x200] . s[200x200] . d2[200x1]. It takes too much time.

Comment: The traceback shows `pandas` functions, presumably its implementation of `matmul`.  Which of your arguments is a dataframe?  `S`?  `data1` and `data2` are 3d, so presumably are numpy arrays, not dataframes.  And just to be sure, what the `dtypes`?

Comment: @hpaulj oh right. I forgot to use to_numpy() on S. Thank you very much!